# Sequence convergence in box topology

Tags: general-topology

If $(f_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ with box topology that converges towards $f\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\geq$1 such that

$$
n\geq N \Rightarrow |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon\quad \text{by all }x\in \mathbb{R}.
$$

I assume that $(f_{n})_{n\geq1}$ is sequence that converges towards $f\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

And then I am stuck. I feel like this is like an analogue to normal sequence convergence in calculus, but I am missing something crucial here..

Stefan gave a tip and I use it here:

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Now by assumption and definition, all neighborouhoods of $f$ $\prod_{x\in\mathbb{R}} ]f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x)+\varepsilon [$ there exists $N\geq 1$ such that $n\geq N$ $\Rightarrow$ $f_{n}\subseteq \prod_{x\in\mathbb{R}} ]f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x)+\varepsilon [$.

Then $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Correct?

Comment: Consider the neighborhood $\prod_{x\in\Bbb R}(f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x)+\varepsilon)$ of $f$.

Comment: Your proof is correct now.